# jquery img width() gives 0

Tags: jquery

strange problem
do you know why this code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'images/img1.jpg';

$(img).on('load', function() {
   alert($(this).width());

});
```

gives 0 in Firefox, Chrome but gives correct value in IE9?
How to get the proper value in all browsers?
using jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: Have you tried setting the `.src` AFTER you bind the `'load'` event?

Comment: Maybe append the image to the body first, that sometimes triggers actual painting. Or just use the `width` *property*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/upelim/2/edit)*

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'images/img1.jpg';

$(img).on('load', function() {
   alert(this.width);
});
```

**[Or with pure JS:](http://jsbin.com/upelim/5/edit)**

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'images/img1.jpg'; 

img.onload = function() {
   alert(this.width);
};
```

Comment: thanks, i used your code but because i need img to be jquery object i did like: $(this).css('width',  this.width);
   $(this).css('height', this.height); after loading  image. After this i can use    alert($(this).width());

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, the order in which you do `.onload = ` and `.src = ` is important; attach the load handler first, then set the location. This becomes obvious when you're dealing with cached images.

Comment: Jack, you are righ. but this dosn't solve the image width problem. first i must set css like $(this).css('width', this.width); or append the image to the body. then i can use jquery width()

Comment: @abiku no it doesn't solve the problem but it will cause some if you do it wrong :-)

Answer (score 3):

Until you append the `image` in to dom `.width()` returns `0`

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png';
$(img).on('load', function() {
    console.log(this.width); // 160
    console.log($(this).context.width); // 160
    console.log($(this).width()); // 0
    $('body').append($(this));
    console.log($(this).width()); // 160
});
```

[**Check this**](http://jsfiddle.net/gCUdN/2/).

Answer (score 1):

As per jQuery documentation `http://api.jquery.com/load-event/`

> Caveats of the load event when used with images:
>   A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut
>       is to execute a function when an     image (or collection of images) have
>       completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should
>       be noted. These are:
>
> 1.It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>       2. It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
>       3. It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
>       4. Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

If you look at the comments down the documentation, many people have the same problem because the load event is not fired in webkit, usually when the src is set as the same before... maybe you want to set a placeholder image and then change the src attribute.

Comment: Interesting piece of information, though it's not the root cause of the problem; the event gets fired.

Answer (score 1):

The way that jQuery determines dimensions of objects is by inspecting the `style` attribute (afaik); since the image never gets added to the DOM, it wouldn't know that.

Having said that, I don't see a particular reason why you need jQuery here:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    alert(this.width);
}
img.src = 'http://example.org/path/to/image.jpg';
```

To set the dimensions using jQuery you could use this:

```
$(this)
    .width(this.width)
    .height(this.height);
```

*Not sure why you need it though, because at rendering time the browser will already know how big the image is, unlike adding an `<img />` to the DOM*

Btw, the order of these statements is important; you should register the load handler *before* setting the `.src` property, otherwise you might miss the load event if an image has been cached by the browser.

Comment: thanks for help. I need this image to be jquery object because im passing it to other javascript function which requires jquery img object as a parameter and i cannot change this function..

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem to provide a jQuery object either way.